# Ignore labeling when field has specific word - ArcMap 10.8

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser, arcgis-10.8

Looking to add a function of my labeling expression to not label feature with the word 'TO". For example, some roads are named '5th TO I-10'. I am using Python as the parser with advanced checked.

Here is what I have so far. The split function is working as intended.

---

```
def FindLabel ([SFEANME]):
   word = 'TO'
   if word in [SFEANME]
      return Null
else
    return [SFEANME].split(" ")[0]
```

---

[SFEANME] is the field for the feature name and is text type.

Here is the error I get when verifying:
"The expression contains an error. Modify the expression and try again.
Error 0 on line 0. SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 3)."

I have tried using "" and without "" around TO, as well as simply: if TO in [SFEANME]

I have not been able to find anyone trying to do something like this in Label Expression so maybe there is a better way, or I do not know how to syntax properly like the error message says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your script:

1. Missing colon (:) at end of `if` line
2. `Null` is not a keyword in Python; use `None` for NULL in Python
3. Missing colon (:) at end of `else` line
4. Inconsistent use of leading whitespace causing poor indentation (Python is very fussy about this... note that I only picked this up when doing a copy/paste, so it may not actually be true in your real code, but is certainly true in the code you have here)

I think the error is complaining about the first of these items.

Try this code, which fixes the problems listed above:

```
def FindLabel ([SFEANME]):
    word = 'TO'
    if word in [SFEANME]:
        return None
    else:
        return [SFEANME].split(" ")[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. That works! I found that I can also filter out all labels that would have 'TO' with SQL Query when Method is set to define classes of features and label each class differently with NOT LIKE '%TO%'.

Comment: @AFang yes, that's probably a better way to do it.   :-)